# Does AWS API Gateway RestAPI allow the creation of path based versioning at the API RestAPI level natively?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

For example, Azure API Management service allows the creation of an API "proxy" front end and the ability to create an api version such as

- https://baseapi.com/**apiName1/v1**

Here is screenshot of that in Azure platform.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-get-started-publish-versions

Does AWS API Gateway RestAPIs allow this type of versioning natively?
If it does, how can I setup for example "v1" of a restAPI?

And if the AWS RestAPI "Stage" is the way to accomplish this, how would I still support the idea of creating stages per environment, while still doing versioning? To me stage seems more associated with environments, whereas versioning is a completely separate concept.

Note: **The rest APIs  are private**

Answer (score 0):

First limitation of private APIs from the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-apis.html) is the following:

> Custom domain names are not supported for private APIs.

This limits what you can do with API Gateway to support multiple versions.

- Run an API Gateway per version - This option grants you complete separation between API versions, however, unfortunately you will need to call a **separate endpoint** per API.
- Deploy a single private API Gateway containing all API versions - This option scopes everything to a single endpoint but as a limitation could become quite complex and hard to manage depending on the number of verbs.

Hopefully in the future this feature from custom domains detailed below will be added.

**Previous Answer - Before known using Private API**

This can be done in API Gateway through the combination of stages and custom domain configuration.

If you deploy each version of API Gateway to either its own [stage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/stages.html) i.e. `v1`, `v2` stage you have seperated the schema and actions between the versions.

Alternatively you can have a separate API and stage for each version of your specific API.

Then create a custom domain name for your API endpoint, under [base path mappings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html) you can map a specific subfolder `v1` to the API and select the `v1` stage in your API Gateway endpoint.

Comment: What about environments? If stages are used for versions, how can I still have Environment separation using stages?

Comment: Also I should have mentioned this is for private APIs

Comment: So if you have environments it might be better to go with the approach of having an API per version so you would have MyAPIv1 with a stage of `dev`, `qa`, `prod` then you production API would map the `v1` mapping to the `MyAPIv1` API with stage `prod`.

Comment: Ah right, for a private API custom domain names are not supported at the moment. You would be restricted to having to manage the versioning based on resource and methods in API Gateway schema.

Comment: I see. So in summary: create RestAPI which is specific for a version, use stages for env, and dns for routing to specific versions. Correct? Also, will this Still work for private APIs?

Comment: The custom domain would have done this, but its currently not supported on private apis unfortunately.

Comment: I’ve updated my question with private APIs specifically. Would You be able to update your answer so that it summarizes the options for private APIs?

Comment: Have added the 2 options that are available to private APIs